# How to get only 1st quarter data from year 2020 and quarter 2nd from2021

Tags: sql-server

How to get only 1st quarter data from year 2020 and quarter 2nd from2021

Comment: You would use a SQL query.  Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following logic:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE date_col >= '20200101' AND date_col < '20200401' OR  -- 1st quarter 2020
      date_col >= '20210401' AND date_col < '20210701';    -- 2nd quarter 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

We dont know your DBMS.

So:

**MySQL:**

```
QUARTER(CURDATE()); -- actual quarter
QUARTER("2020-01-01 09:34:21"); --in your case
```

**Oracle:**

```
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Q') -- actual quarter
```

**TSql:**

```
CONCAT (TO_CHAR(your_date, 'YYYY-'),concat ('Q', date_part(quarter, your_date) ))
```